# Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems

I have a Sinatra app using Postgres via Activerecord. I'm using RVM on a Mac and a number of gems including:

```
activerecord
activesupport
```

When I run the server (thin), I get an error:

> Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'.
>   Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use
>   an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add
>   the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

The adapter is set to `postgresql` in the config, and I've checked my RVM and paths: My Gem install path is set properly, and I can see the appropriate gems installed properly, and the specific adapter is there too, so really not sure what could be happening or how to further troubleshoot this?

Using Ruby 2.0.0-p598, activerecord and activesupport 4.1.4

--

Further debugging attempts:

`ruby -v`

> ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]

`which ruby`

> /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby

`gem env` (relevant parts):

> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin
> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598
>   - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global
> - SHELL PATH:
>
>   - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin
>   - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/bin
>   - /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin

`ls $GEM_HOME/gems`

> activerecord-4.1.4
>   activesupport-4.1.4

Really at a loss for what else I can look into

---

`database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: example_db
  username: example_user
  password: example_password
  host: localhost
```

Comment: Please post your database.yml file. (Be sure to first remove any passwords in it)

Comment: Have you required activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adaptor anywhere?

Comment: I'll add my database.yml, i didn't require that adaptor anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

A next debugging step I took was to try using rvm to install a whole new version of ruby. This worked, so I used rvm to completely remove my old version of ruby with `rvm remove 2.0.0-p598` and reinstall it again `rvm install 2.0.0-p598`.

I still have no idea what may have happened, but perhaps somehow something in the gem caches/builds were corrupted, so if anyone runs into a weird error like this where everything is in place but still doesn't work, try clearing everything with rvm and reinstalling.